# How to check array object and array?

Tags: php, arrays

**First array:**

```
[VariationSpecificsSet] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [NameValueList] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Name] => Size
                                [Value] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => 5FT King Size
                                        [1] => 4FT6 Double
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Name] => Main Colour
                                [Value] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Brown
                                        [1] => Black
                                    )
                            )
                     )
          )
```

**Second Array:**

```
[Variation] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [StartPrice] => 14.99
                [Quantity] => 12
                [VariationSpecifics] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [NameValueList] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [Name] => Size
                                [Value] => No.10-1M
                            )
                    )
        )
```

examine above two arrays

i want to store value NameValueList in database but the problem is sometimes it is `SimpleXMLElement Object` and sometimes it is `Array`

how can i store them ...??

Comment: you can check it by `is_object` and `is_array` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect is by `is_array()`.

```
$myVal=$test['NameValueList'];
if(is_array($myVal) && count($myVal)>0){
    foreach($myVal as $item){
        echo $item->Name.":".echo $item->Value;
    }
} else {
    echo $myVal->Name.":".echo $myVal->Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using json_encode like below.
You can convert the object to array.

```
$array=json_decode(json_encode($object),true);
```